# Variables in imported scss files generate error in Scout's log

Tags: compass-sass, sass

Below is my main scss file for my current project.
I use the variables also in css_ve.scss which is imported afterwards.
The generated css files work as expected but Scout throws errors in the log panel because it can't find the variables declarations in css_ve.scss.
This is a minor issue but I would like to know how to prevent these errors from occuring.
One solution would be to create a scss file only for variables and import it from all the other files but I would like to avoid to have too many scss files scattered in my project.

Thanks in advance!

```
/* VARIABLES ------------------------------ */

/* fonts */ 
$font-family-1: 'Arial', 'Meiryo', 'MS Gothic', 'MS UI Gothic', 'MS PGothic', 'Arial Unicode';
$font-family-2: 'MS UI Gothic', 'MS PGothic', 'Arial Unicode';
$font-size: 14px;

/* colors */
$color-1: #000000; /* black */
$color-2: #ffffff; /* white */  
$color-3: #CCCCCC; /* grey */
$color-4: #00A3AF; /* green */
$color-5: #FF6600; /* orange */

/* IMPORTS ------------------------------ */

/* validationEngine */ 
@import "validation_engine/css_ve.scss";

/* STYLES ------------------------------ */
```

....

Answer (score 0):

```
@import "validation_engine/css_ve"; perhaps?
```